# CSS - Top menu with horizontally centered one- and two-line-long entries – without flex?

Tags: html, css, menu, alignment

I'm trying to build a top menu that horizontally centers a few entries that are one or two lines long using simple `div` and `display:inline-table`. The problem is that I haven't found a way to center the entries that are only one line long (Item0 and Item1), unless I use `display:flex`. I would like to do this without specifying the height in pixel.

The yellow boxes around the entries are just for reference, so that I can better see what is going on which each entry.

Since I'm very new to front-end development, I would like to know if there is a better way to do that.

Here is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tudulik/1/embed?output).

Thanks!
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `display:table/table-cell` see snippet below (I've simplified your code a bit):

#### Snippet

```css
body {
  font-family: ubuntu;
}
#nav1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  display: table
}
.menus {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: right;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 8px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav1">
  <div class="menus">
    Item 0 (1 line)
  </div>
  <div class="menus">
    Item 1 (1 line)
  </div>
  <div class="menus">
    Item 2 long text
    <br>item 2 long text
  </div>
  <div class="menus">
    Item 3 long text
    <br>item 3 long text
  </div>
  <div class="menus">
    Item 4 long text
    <br>item 4 long text production
  </div>
  <div class="menus">
    Item 5 long text
    <br>item 5 long text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks dippas! ..I will give this a try.